# Visual Studio extension for scripting objects with debug values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am looking for a Visual Studio extension or function that could copy the values of an object at debug time, and then script the creation of that object and assignment of the values gathered at debug time to the publicly accessible attributes to the object.

For instance, if I am manually testing a POST request on an ASP.Net MVC webapp, and I find that it breaks when I enter special characters into one-or-more fields, I would like to hit a breakpoint at the beginning of the action method, click a button titled "Generate object script", and have a C# script created similar as follows:

```
var obj = new YourViewModel();
obj.Foo = "ThisIsWhatWasCaptured!"
obj.Bar = "AnotherAttribute";
```

Obviously the idea is that it would be easy to programmatically recreate the scenario that occurred in a unit test without manually having to write out the object creation.

Is anyone aware of an existing tool that does this?

Comment: VS allows you to create your own debugging visualisers through which you could gleam such data, whether or not you want any fancy front end is up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object Exporter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter) extension lets you export out an object while debugging in C# object initialization format.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I was asking for... thanks!